# Finding an harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I was doing an exercice that i'm struggling doing.

Consider the function $u$ defined on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by
$$
u\left(x,y\right)=e^{x}\left(x\cos\left(y\right)-y\sin\left(y\right)\right)
$$

***1]***  Prove that $u$ is harmonic on $\mathbb{R}^2$

***2]*** Find a function $v$ so that $f=u+iv$ be holomorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. Explicite $f$ using the variable $z$ using analytic extension theorem.

1. My attempt :
   $$
   \frac{\partial u }{\partial x}\left(x,y\right)=e^{x}\left(x\cos\left(y\right)-y\sin\left(y\right)+\cos\left(y\right)\right)
   $$
   So I found
   $$
   \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\left(x,y\right)=e^{x}\left(x\cos\left(y\right)-y\sin\left(y\right)+2\cos\left(y\right)\right)
   $$
   And for $y$
   $$
   \frac{\partial u }{\partial y}\left(x,y\right)=e^{x}\left(-x\sin\left(y\right)-\sin\left(y\right)-y\cos\left(y\right)\right)
   $$
   hence
   $$
   \frac{\partial^2 u }{\partial y^2}\left(x,y\right)=e^{x}\left(-x\cos\left(y\right)-\cos\left(y\right)+y\sin(y)-\cos(y)\right)
   $$
   Finally I happily found that

> $$
> \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\left(x,y\right)+\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2}\left(x,y\right)=0
> $$

Is it all good for the first one ?

2. I was wondering how I could link this to being holomorphic, how should I proceed ?

Comment: Hint: Use Cauchy-Riemann's conditions. You've, probably, showed in a theorem that if a function is analytic, then derivatives are satisfying harmonic function property. Now, when you have $u(x, y)$ just use the conditions and total derivative property. Hope I haven't made it any harder.

Comment: Function in $C$ is holomorphic iff it is analytic.

Comment: Yes, so i should verify that $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\left(x,y\right)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}\left(x,y\right) \text{ and }\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}\left(x,y\right)=-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\left(x,y\right) $$ ?

Comment: Yes, but you already have the $u(x, y)$ function. So finding what $v(x, y)$ is is just solving a first order differential equation of total differential.

Comment: Thanks I've understood !

Comment: Bare in mind. The $1.$ part is was necessary. Once you've proven the function is holomorphic, you are sure the other part (in this case imaginary part) of an $entire$ function exists. It's always done in that order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find a particular $v(x,y)$ that satisfies

$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = e^x(x\sin y + y\cos y + \sin y) $$
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = e^x(x\cos y - y\sin y + \cos y) $$

The process is straightforward. Start by integrating one of the partials, let's say the second one
$$ v(x,y) = \int e^x(x\cos y - y\sin y + \cos y) dy = e^x(x\sin y + y\cos y) + g(x) $$

Then differentiate the other way
$$ \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = e^x(x\sin y + y\cos y + \sin y) + f'(x) $$

By comparison, $f'(x) = 0$, so $f(x) = C = 0$. Therefore
$$ v(x,y) = e^x(x\sin y + y\cos y) $$

---

Let's simplify the complex function
$$ \begin{align} 
f(z) = u(x,y) + iv(x,y) &= e^x(x\cos y - y\sin y + ix\sin y + iy\cos y) \\
&= e^x\big((x+iy)\cos y + i(x+iy)\sin y\big) \\
&= e^x(x+iy)(\cos y + i\sin y) \\
&= (x+iy)e^{x+iy} \\
&= ze^z 
\end{align} $$

As for the last question, if $u$ is harmonic (which you've proven), then $v$ is guaranteed to exist. Since they're both continuous and twice-differentiable on $\Bbb R^2$, $f(z)$ must be holomorphic on $\Bbb C$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The form of the function $u(x,y)$ suggests looking at $e^z\cdot z,$ for both parts 1. and 2.

Answer (score 1):

If $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R^2$ defined as $f(x,y)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)$ is harmonic, then $\tilde f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ defined as $\tilde f(x+iy)=u(x+iy)+iv(x+iy)$ is holomorphic.

Comment: How can I use that ?

Answer (score 1):

The real part of the holomorphic function
$$
e^{x+iy}(x+iy)=e^x[(x\cos(y)-y\sin(y))+i(y\cos(y)+x\sin(y))]
$$
is
$$
e^x(x\cos(y)-y\sin(y))
$$
and the real part of a holomorphic function is harmonic.

Comment: But what i have done is ok no ?

Comment: Well, this is my hint, exploded.

Comment: @Atmos: it is. You can use the [Cauchy-Riemann Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations) to compute the [harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_conjugate) of the function given.

Comment: @zhw.: indeed it is, I hadn't noticed before. I have upvoted your answer. If you feel my answer is simply a duplicate, I will delete it.

Comment: @robjohn No, it's fine. Actually I don't even know why I complained. This happens all the time at MSE. I just upvoted your answer.